# AngularJS - Forçando bind do campo input

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Boa Tarde pessoal!
Eu li que por padrão o AngularJS exige que os campos tenham alguma interação do usuário para efetuar o binding. 
como faço para ignorar isso e enviar o que tiver no campo input, mesmo sem a interação com o usuário?
Obrigado.

Meu JavaScript está no próprio hmtl, eu uso o codigo deste site.
https://viacep.com.br/exemplo/javascript/

porém, eu tenho um arquivo esterno dentro da pasta controller (laravel 5), chamado cadastro.js
a função de salvar dentro do cadastro.js é essa.

"self.email = {};
    self.salvar = function () {
        var erros = [];
        // Validações
        if (!self.email.email) {
            erros.push('O campo E-mail é obrigatório');
        }

```
    if (!self.email.contato) {
        erros.push('O campo Contato é obrigatório');
    }

    if (erros.length > 0) {
        alertService.add('danger', erros);
    }
    else {
        $uibModalInstance.close(self.email);
    }

}; "
```

aqui são alguns dos campos dentro do meu html que uso funções do angularjs.
"

CEP

Endereco
   
"

Comment: Que eu saiba, se você usar o ng-model, independente da ação do usuário ele vai enviar o que existe lá.

Comment: entao, eu tenho uns campos de input que são preenchidos pelo javascritpt, acontece que na hora do model salvar, ele nao sava os campos preenchidos, ao menos que eu digite algo neles.

Comment: Isso não deveria acontecer, tente imprimer os campos com console.log para saber se eles realmente estão preenchidos.

Comment: Se você postar seu código, a gente tenta ajudar...